# Table Driven WHERE Clause Using LIKE

Tags: sql-server-2008, where-clause, sql-like

What I have:

```
WHERE (dbo.Field1 LIKE '% contact made %' OR dbo.Field1 LIKE '% talked to %')
```

I need something like the following:

```
WHERE (dbo.Field1 LIKE IN (SELECT Pattern FROM PatternTable))

PatternTable
------------
% contact made %
% talked to %
% called in %
% spoke with %
% spoke to %
```

---

Similiar question is [SQL Where Clause with LIKE and IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186801/sql-where-clause-with-like-and-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle you can do

```
SELECT * FROM dbo
JOIN PatterTable ON dbo.Field LIKE PatterTable.pattern
```

I would think this will work in SQL Server as well.

Comment: Yeah, this is somehow not obvious.  When I first saw something like this I was strangely surprised.

Comment: Now that I see the syntax and see the results of a working sample, it makes perfect sense. Similiar to joining on a date range.

Comment: Right, exactly.  Once you see it, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use dynamic sql:

http://www.dba-sql-server.com/sql_server_tips/t_super_sql_460_dynamic_sql.htm